# DateTime columns values get changed when exporting from vb.net DGV to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, date, datetime, types

I am trying to export **DGV** displaying data to Excel and it's working fine with following code. The problem is the **date** or **datetime** columns get some random numbers after exporting to excel. Also I have to change the column and select and data type to `short` date to display dates.

The following code has **DGV** data from **SQL**. I want the date column in cell range C:C to be as date in excel.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    picLoading_TO.Visible = True
    picLoading_TO.BringToFront()

    Try
        Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim sheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing


        excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        'excel.Visible = True
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
        sheet1 = DirectCast(workbook.Sheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

        Dim StartCol As Integer = 1
        Dim StartRow As Integer = 1
        Dim j As Integer = 0, i As Integer = 0
        Dim visibleCols As Integer = 0

        Dim sOutput As String = ""
        ' Dim sDelimiter As String = txtDelimiter.Text


        'Write Headers
        For j = 0 To dgvOrders.Columns.Count - 1
            If dgvOrders.Columns(j).Visible Then

                Dim myRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = DirectCast(sheet1.Cells(StartRow, StartCol + visibleCols), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
                myRange.Value2 = dgvOrders.Columns(j).HeaderText
                visibleCols += 1
            End If
        Next

        StartRow += 1


        'Write datagridview content
        For i = 0 To dgvOrders.Rows.Count - 1
            visibleCols = 0

            For j = 0 To dgvOrders.Columns.Count - 1
                If dgvOrders.Columns(j).Visible Then

                    Dim myRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = DirectCast(sheet1.Cells(StartRow + i, StartCol + visibleCols), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
                    myRange.Value2 = If(dgvOrders(j, i).Value Is Nothing, "", dgvOrders(j, i).Value)
                    visibleCols += 1

                End If

            Next

        Next

        picLoading_TO.Visible = False
        picLoading_TO.SendToBack()
        excel.Visible = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain those numbers are random?  That seems unlikely if you can convert them to valid date-times merely by changing the formatting, or are those results nonsensical?

Comment: As far as I know a `Date` in Excel internally is a floating point number where the value of 1 is representing 1/1/1900. The fractional part of the floating point number is used for the time.
In .NET a `Date` internally is a `Structure` which counts in steps of 100 nano-second ticks The value of 0 represents midnight of the 1st of january of the year 1.
Maybe that helps you in figuring out what's happening.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, those numbers are not random actually. format of that column is as General in excel. if I change the format to Data, it shows correct dates.

Comment: And then all you have to do is format that columm in your code to a date format

Comment: How to do that ? could you please show me ?

Comment: I suggest you consult with the writer of the code. Without understanding, it would be easy to mess something up.  An alternative would be for you to write a separate macro that would do the formatting, perhaps tie it to a button, or trigger it when this macro is finished.